# What is wrong with the synchronization in following code

Tags: java, synchronization

SYNCHRONIZATION

I have declared a `class b` which has a synchronized method which is accessed in `class c`:

```
class b {
    String msg;

    public synchronized void foo() {
        System.out.print("[" + msg);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // Threads go to sleeep

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught" + e);
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}

class a implements Runnable {
    b ob;

    Thread t;

    a(String msg, b obb) {
        ob = obb;
        ob.msg = msg;
        t = new Thread(this); // creating a thread
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        ob.foo(); // calling method of class b
    }

    public static void main(String... a) {
        b obb = new b();
        a ob = new a("Hello", obb); /* PASSING */
        a ob1 = new a("Synch", obb); /* THE */
        a ob2 = new a("World", obb);/* MESSAGE */

        try {
            ob.t.join();
            ob1.t.join();
            ob2.t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting the output:

```
[Hello]
[Synch]
[World]
```

But the code gives:

```
[World]
[World]
[World]
```

Help me with some suggestions. I am a naive JAVA user.

Comment: Please post a formatted code

Comment: There is too much missing - Why should it write anything, where is foo being called, and why should it say Hello Synch World?

Comment: Java is pass by reference for objects, so `ob.msg=msg;`is overwriting the common `b` message (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you have set `ob.msg=msg;` `msg` gets overridden by the threads. So you have the same message for all the Threads.

In the constructor of each Thread of class `a` you are passing the same object of class `b`. Now all three threads are setting the value of `msg` of the instance of class `b`. So one value overrides the other. What you have is the value set by last thread i.e. `World`.

IMO: Save the msg as an instance variable in each thread and pass it to the `foo` method as a parameter.

And please follow Java naming convention i.e. Camel Casing

Comment: Added explanation to the answer.

Comment: But before msg gets overriden doesn't the value "Hello" gets printed in foo? And after the first thread sleeps the control comes back to main()

Comment: Its unpredictable whether the value gets overridden first or the foo method gets executed 1st. Either way to make ur code predicatable you need to pass the value to the foo method.

Answer (score 1):

use the following code to get the expected answer.

class b {
    // String msg;

```
public void foo(String msg) {
    System.out.print("[" + msg);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // Threads go to sleeep

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Caught" + e);
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```

}

public class Threading implements Runnable {

```
    b ob;
String msg;
Thread t;

Threading(String message, b obb) {
    ob = obb;
    msg = message;
    t = new Thread(this); // creating a thread
    t.start();
}

public void run() {
    synchronized (ob) {
        ob.foo(msg); // calling method of class b
    }

}

public static void main(String... a) {
    b obb = new b();
    Threading ob = new Threading("Hello", obb); /* PASSING */
    Threading ob2 = new Threading("World", obb); /* THE */
    Threading ob1 = new Threading("Synch", obb);/* MESSAGE */

    try {
        ob.t.join();
        ob1.t.join();
        ob2.t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Caught" + e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thnx pnathan....
But in my code before msg gets overriden doesn't the value "Hello" gets printed in foo? And after the first thread sleeps, the control comes back to main()

Comment: no steve in your code what happened value is got overriden each time before it get printed because there is a sleep before printing the value so it prints the last value (i.e world) each time which is supplied.

Comment: pnathan actually the first print statement is before sleep statement. Sorry I am really not getting this point

Comment: i think we can not predict that value get overriden or method get executed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all reformat your code. It is very hard to read.
Second when you call `ob.msg = msg;` it overrites msg value in ob and as it is not synchronized so you cannot actually predict what the output will be.